# What is the Best Practice for this Scenario - jQuery & CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to web development so I'm unsure whether this is the most efficient way of achieving this task.

I'm currently writing an online store and on the products page I have x amount of products fetched from a database back end. I am then using the result array to generate dynamic html/css in order to output:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo('
        <div class="box">
            <div class="product"><img src="upload/' . $row['prod_image'] . '" /></div>
            <h3> ' . $row['prod_title'] . '</h3>
            <div class="create-user">
                <p>More Details...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
                <p><img src="upload/class.png"/>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the x icon.</p>
            </div>
            <p class="price">Price: <span class="red">£' . $row['prod_price'] . '</span></p>
            <div><a href="#"></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/addtocart.gif" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
        </div>'
    );
}
```

Now when you click on "more details" it should call the jQuery dialog function for each particular product in order to open the "dialog" tag, but this only seems to work for the first product and non of the others.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#create-user').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

I have managed to get around this, but it seems like a dirty way, and this is what I did. I added a unique div id to each product and then kept them inline with the JavaScript using increments:

```
$incr = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo('
        <div class="box">   
            <div class="product"><img src="upload/' . $row['prod_image'] . '" /></div>
            <h3> ' . $row['prod_title'] . '</h3>
            <div id="create-user' . $incr . '">
                <p>More Details...</p>
            </div>
            <p class="price">Price: <span class="red">£' . $row['prod_price'] . '</span></p>
            <div><a href="#"></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/addtocart.gif" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div id="dialog' . $incr . '" title="Basic dialog">
                <p><img src="upload/class.png"/>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the x icon.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
        </div>'
    );
    $incr++;
}
```

And the JS to go with that:

```
$(function() {
    var diag_num = 0;
    while(diag_num < 4) {
        diag_num +=1;
        $("#dialog" + diag_num ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $('#create-user' + diag_num).click(function() {
            $('#dialog' + diag_num).dialog('open');
        });
    }
});
```

While this methodology works fine for a set number of products per page, and there's no problem in doing it this way because I will only have around 10 per page anyway (so I know my vars length), I can't help but think that this is a bad way of doing it.

I've also looked into using a "div class", then assign all products to that same class, use jQuery class selector to find the class "create-user", then use the "parent" methods in order to climb back up the DOM tree to find the next "dialog" class. This worked but when you open a dialog it opens one per product on the page, hence my reasoning for making the "DIVS" unique.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: rework your JQuery. classes are selected by ('.classname'). you currently select by id

Comment: You should think about using a template engine like **[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)**. As your code will get more complex it won't get any easier to maintain those huge `echo`-blocks.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thanks, I'm all for that. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Vogel612 You're correct in what you say. However even when changing to .classname for the selector, it will obviously select all 4 products and open all dialogs if they're assigned to that same class.

Comment: @DaleBetts right. further rework of the JQuery could fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.create-user').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('.dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

this should work with the first code sample you posted.

on click it selects the next item with class dialog and opens it.

the `$(this)` here stands for the clicked "More Details...". siblings() fetches sll siblings, if you add a selector it filters them by the given selector. as you have wrapped your items in a box no other dialog should be selected.